# tezos-node syncing failed: "Json_encoding.construct: consequence of bad union"

Tags: node, tezos-client, tezos-admin-client

I'm trying to get our `tezos-node` going again, but no matter what I do it seems to fail on [block 1195254](https://blockchair.com/tezos/block/1195254). Rebooting and upgrading the node haven't fixed the issue. Do I need to roll back a few blocks and try syncing from there, is there a method to do that?

I originally noticed the error on node version `06398944 (2020-02-11 14:29:14 +0100)` but upgraded to the latest `opam` version but received the same error:

```
./tezos-node --version
e69b63f1 (2020-09-04 13:28:39 +0200) (7.4)

Nov  2 04:04:58 - block_validator_process_external: Block validator started on pid 3752069
Nov  2 04:04:58 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline: unexpected error while fetching headers
Nov  2 04:04:58 - validator.peer: Worker crashed [node_peer_validator]:
Nov  2 04:04:58 - validator.peer: End_of_file
Nov  2 04:05:00 - validator.block: Validation of block BL3xFTUPQ1tMC4nTFxUAodNcWL6ppvRomzGwsJ18ozchAhsLPPE failed
Nov  2 04:05:00 - validator.block: Request pushed on 2020-11-02T04:04:54-00:00, treated in 4.768s, completed in 1.397s ,
Nov  2 04:05:00 - validator.block: (Invalid_argument "Json_encoding.construct: consequence of bad union")
Nov  2 04:05:00 - block_validator_process_external: The process terminated abnormally with value 1
Nov  2 04:05:00 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline: unexpected error while fetching headers
Nov  2 04:05:00 - block_validator_process_external: Block validator started on pid 3752074
Nov  2 04:05:00 - validator.peer: Worker crashed [node_peer_validator]:
Nov  2 04:05:00 - validator.peer: (Invalid_argument "Json_encoding.construct: consequence of bad union")
```

No blocks are rejected:

```
./tezos-admin-client list rejected blocks
No invalid blocks.
```

I can't use the client to pull the block (1195254), though the previous block (1195253) returns via this command:

```
./tezos-client rpc get /chains/main/blocks/BL3xFTUPQ1tMC4nTFxUAodNcWL6ppvRomzGwsJ18ozchAhsLPPE/header

Error:
  Did not find service: GET http://localhost:8732/describe/chains/main/blocks/BL3xFTUPQ1tMC4nTFxUAodNcWL6ppvRomzGwsJ18ozchAhsLPPE/header?recurse=no
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello and thanks for reporting this. It looks like it deserves an issue on the Tezos' gitlab https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/issues.

In the meantime you could try to reproduce the error with version v8.0~rc1 of the node, which has the patch that fixes the display of protocol errors. It will give us more info than "consequence of bad union".

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem this morning. Resolved by importing a fresh snapshot.
I only add my logging detail to this question because of the comment t
'It will give us more info than "consequence of bad union".'
Running the latest... git rev-parse HEAD
e69b63f128701b2cdad665e8037a330305f591ce
Hopefully this is useful. Thanks.

`Nov 13 07:49:26 - validator.peer: (Invalid_argument "Json_encoding.construct: consequence of bad union")
Nov 13 07:49:26 - validator.peer: Worker started for NetXdQprcVkpa:idrxBrNuUMRN
Nov 13 07:49:28 - validator.block: Validation of block BLf7AxHFzVBHGGTCEAYPn71TjqbxXwN1dQCEbVgrvRuekxLhQUR failed
Nov 13 07:49:28 - validator.block: Request pushed on 2020-11-13T14:49:22-00:00, treated in 4.341s, completed in 2.72s ,
Nov 13 07:49:28 - validator.block: (Invalid_argument "Json_encoding.construct: consequence of bad union")
Nov 13 07:49:28 - block_validator_process_external: The process terminated abnormally with value 1
Nov 13 07:49:31 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline: unexpected error while fetching headers
Nov 13 07:49:31 - block_validator_process_external: Block validator started on pid 1875
Nov 13 07:49:37 - validator.peer: Worker crashed [node_peer_validator]:
Nov 13 07:49:37 - validator.peer: (Invalid_argument "Json_encoding.construct: consequence of bad union")
Nov 13 07:49:44 - validator.block: Validation of block BLf7AxHFzVBHGGTCEAYPn71TjqbxXwN1dQCEbVgrvRuekxLhQUR failed
Nov 13 07:49:44 - validator.block: Request pushed on 2020-11-13T14:49:22-00:00, treated in 6.198s, completed in 15.394s ,
Nov 13 07:49:44 - validator.block: (Invalid_argument "Json_encoding.construct: consequence of bad union")
Nov 13 07:49:44 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline: unexpected error while fetching headers
Nov 13 07:49:44 - block_validator_process_external: The process terminated abnormally with value 1
Nov 13 07:49:44 - validator.peer: Worker started for NetXdQprcVkpa:idshzyH6TRtV
Nov 13 07:49:44 - validator.peer: Worker crashed [node_peer_validator]:
Nov 13 07:49:44 - validator.peer: (Invalid_argument "Json_encoding.construct: consequence of bad union")
Nov 13 07:49:44 - validator.block: Validation of block BLf7AxHFzVBHGGTCEAYPn71TjqbxXwN1dQCEbVgrvRuekxLhQUR failed
Nov 13 07:49:44 - validator.block: Request pushed on 2020-11-13T14:49:37-00:00, treated in 7.67s, completed in 14.219ms , Unix error in write: Broken pipe
Nov 13 07:49:44 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline: unexpected error while fetching headers`